# How can i write one writes to many classes in Play Framework using inheritance

Tags: json, scala, playframework, case-class

As example i have classes

```
trait Advert

case class Car(brand: String) extends Advert
case class House(price: Long) extends Advert

object AdvertCompanion[T <: Advert]
object Car extends AdvertComnation[Car]
object House extends AdvertComnation[House]
```

I don't want to write Json.writes[..] in every companion of case class. I want to write it in object AdvertCompanion. But then i do it, i get error `No unapply function found`

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since play is reading by reflection the names of the apply method parameters, and generates the required methods according to that.